# XSLT generate tag

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to generate a tag abc in XSLT. I see that we have to specify in XSLT as follows:

```
<string name ="abc"></string>
```

Bit in the output i get

```
<string name ="abc"></string>
```

But i need the outpult like

```
<string>abc</string>
```

Please advice.

Comment: What are your input and output?

Comment: My XSLT is like -<xsl:variable name="nm"><xsl:value-of select="@textType" /></xsl:variable>
<object id="{@textType}" class="com.FontResolver" method="resolveFont">
<string><xsl:text>{$nm}</xsl:text></string></object>
<font idref="{@textType}"/> and i need an output like - <object id="Calibri"class="com.FontResolver" method="resolveFont">
<string>Calibri</string>
</object>

Answer (score 0):

The attribute-value-template syntax `{$nm}` only works in the value of an attribute. In the content of an element, you can instead use `xsl:value-of` as in the following revision of your code. It is not necessary to wrap `xsl:text` around the `xsl:value-of` element.

```
<xsl:variable name="nm"><xsl:value-of select="@textType" /></xsl:variable>
<object id="{@textType}" class="com.FontResolver" method="resolveFont">
<string><xsl:value-of select="$nm"/></string></object>
<font idref="{@textType}"/>
```

On the other hand, `xsl:value-of` is used only for text, not for markup. If on some other occasion you want to generate XML elements, then instead of using `xsl:value-of` you can use `xsl:copy-of` to insert the node set that is the value of a variable or other expression; or you can use `xsl:element` to generate any XML element.